# remove variable from path powershell script, If statements

Tags: windows, powershell, path

I have a piece of code that requires to change the path for the current terminal session.Is there a way to remove just part of the path? I need python removed from path before the application starts. Also my if statements are not functioning and I am not sure why

```html
function anaconda { 
    $key = "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
    param(    
    [Alias('d')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Deactivate')]
    [switch] $Deactivate
    ,
    [Alias('a')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Activate')]
    [switch] $Activate
    )

    if ($Activate) {
        & 'C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Anaconda3'
        
        #some way to remove C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\; C:\Program Files\Python310\ from path
        
    } 
    elseif ($Deactivate) 
    {
        & 'C:\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda deactivate 'C:\Anaconda3'
        $env:path = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name PATH).Path
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes the paths, now I just need help with those If statements.

```html
$Environment = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine")
foreach ($path in ($Environment).Split(";"))
    {
    if ($path -like "C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\")
        {
        $Environment = $Environment.Replace($Path ,"")
        }
        if ($path -like "C:\Program Files\Python310\")
        {
        $Environment = $Environment.Replace($Path ,"")
        }
    }
$env:PATH = $Environment
```